# Expanded list of JUnit tests

Tags: eclipse, junit

When I am running my JUnit tests, I see such a picture:

[image: picture1]

But I want to see this by default (test's list should be expanded):

[image: picture2]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you click on the `arrow` icon (near minimize/maximize), on the bar view and deselect `Show Tests in Hierarchy` ?
Or play with different layout under `Layout` (same icon)

Comment: I presume this option is saved in junit preferences, so if you switch workspace it will not remember